# Showing that $x+y+z \le 2\left(\frac {x^2}{y+z}+ \frac {y^2}{x+z}+ \frac {z^2}{x+y}\right)$ for positive $x, y, z$?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Please, even more than the solution I would like to understand how get better at solving inequalities. Currently my only method is to just blindly try different manipulations to see if they work.

This problem comes from the book *C-S Master Class* so I think there is a solution by C-S, but others are welcome too. Here are some things I tried for this inequality:

**Trial 1:** Let $w = (x+y)(y+z)(x+z)$. Multiplying both sides by $w$ makes it

$$xw+yw+zw \le x^2(x+z)(x+y)+y^2(x+y)(y+z)+z^2(x+z)(y+z)$$

The LHS looks like C-S so I tried to apply C-S to the sequences $\{x(y+z), y(x+z), z(x+y)\}$ and $\{(x+y)(x+z), (x+y)(y+z), (x+z, y) \}$. So it remain to check that my RHS is equal the the RHS of the C-S inequality; but the degrees don't match.

**Trial 2:** Let $a = x+y, b=y+z, c = x+z$. Then the inequality becomes 
$$a+b+c \le \dfrac {(a-b+c)^2}{b}+ \dfrac {(b-c+a)^2}{c}+\dfrac {(c-a+b)^2}{a}$$

and from here I don't know where I would apply C-S.

Comment: $\frac{x^2}{y+z}=\frac{x(x+y+z)}{y+z}-x$.

Comment: Trial 2 leads to a solution; if you expand it out, simplicity then repeatedly apply the AM-GM inequality for $n=2$, namely $a^2 + b^2 \geq 2ab$. Its not pretty and doesn't use C-S unfortunately, but it does work.

Comment: @userabc Is that a trick that people just memorize to deal with terms of the form $\dfrac {x^2}{y+z}$, or did you just come up with it?

Comment: @Cataline I'm curious, is that something you can just tell by looking? Or did you actually expand it out and solve it?

Comment: @Ovi I did it out myself to be sure. But even by looking it seemed pretty likely that it would be possible. Homogeneous polynomials are (usually!) quite easily to solve using AM-GM, and having a single term in the denominator is nice too. Both these things make it look much more manageable than the original expression.

Comment: @Cataline Thanks? If it's not too much, I have two more questions: 1) After we expand, how do we know which terms to break off to prove separately? 2) Are there some general strategies for solving inequalities with homogenous polynomials? Based on my limited experience I broke off  $a^2bc+b^2ac+c^2ab \le a^3b+b^3c+c^3a$, but I wouldn't have been able to prove it myself unless I saw this one trick; the trick I saw in another problem was to divide both sides by $abc$ giving $a+b+c \le \dfrac {a^2}{c} + \dfrac {b^2}{a} + \dfrac {c^2}{b}$, and from here we use AM-GM: $\dfrac {a^2}{c}+c \ge 2a$

Comment: $\dfrac {b^2}{a}+a \ge 2b$ and $\dfrac {c^2}{b}+b \ge 2c$; adding these three gives the result.

Answer (score 2):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b+c)^2}{b}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b+c)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}b}=\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a+b+c}=a+b+c.$$
The best way I think is C-S:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{y+z}\geq\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(y+z)}=\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{2(x+y+z)}=\frac{x+y+z}{2}.$$
I see also at least five different proofs.

Comment: That indeed seems like the best proof, and thank you very much because I think I learned a new technique from you. If you don't mind, can you give just the idea for some other proof?

Comment: We can get a sum of squares, which $\geq0.$